# What is the difference between "criteria of" and "criteria for"?

Tags: grammar, semantics

The criteria of 'dog-ness' are the following...

The criteria for an animal to be a dog are the following...

Are both phrases correct and, if so, what's the difference between them? Are 'of' and 'for' interchangeable?

Comment: In this context, 'of' and 'for' are interchangeable. Both uses are correct, and there is no semantic difference.

Comment: ... but 'for' [is more common](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=criteria+for%2Ccriteria+of).

Answer (score 0):

In this case they mean the same thing. 'of' and 'for' in this case roughly represent 'belonging to'